# Comprobar si una entrada numérica por promt está vacía

Tags: javascript

Necesito, para una tarea, pedir datos por prompt, chequear que esos datos estén ingresados y sean "correctos" o acordes a lo que se pide, y luego realizar funciones con esos datos. El problema es que para chequear que la edad sea correcta creé, de manera muy simple, esta comprobación:

```
`let edad = parseInt(prompt("Cuántos años tenés?"));
let checkEdad = ()=> {
    if (edad == NaN || edad === "" || edad <= 0){
        error = true;
    } else {
        error = false;
    }
    console.log(edad);
    console.log(error);
}
checkEdad();`
```

Por consola muestra que si el campo está vacío o escribo cualquier cosa, edad es igual a NaN, pero igualmente me dice q error es false. No entiendo que estoy haciendo mal.
Gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema venia dado por como tratas `NaN`.

Según la sintaxis de [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), dice esto:

> Si el primer carácter no se puede convertir en número, parseInt
> devuelve NaN.
>
> Para fines aritméticos, el valor NaN no es un número en ninguna base.
> Puede llamar a la función isNaN para determinar si el resultado de
> parseInt es NaN. Si se pasa NaN en operaciones aritméticas, la
> operación resultante también será NaN.

`isNaN` convierte el argumento a número y devuelve `true` si el valor resultante es `NaN`.

Por lo tanto, he realizado el cambio de `edad == NaN` por la función `isNaN(edad)` y ahora ya devuelve resultados distintos segun los valores introducidos.

```js
let edad = parseInt(prompt("Cuántos años tenés?"));
let checkEdad = ()=> {
    if (isNaN(edad) || edad === "" || edad <= 0){
        error = true;
    } else {
        error = false;
    }
    console.log(edad);
    console.log(error);
}
checkEdad();
```

Comment: La base es opcional y si no se especifica se asume base 10 por defecto, a excepción del resultado del análisis de la cadena recibida. Indicar que se debe poner la base siempre al usar `parseInt` no es del todo correcto, sobretodo si la base a usar será 10. Se puede omitir sin problemas el parámetro de base cuando es igual a 10. Saludos

Comment: @MauricioContreras: Pues vas a tener razón, no leí hasta tan abajo en el propio enlace que puse yo mismo.  Edito mi respuesta en breve

Comment: @MauricioContreras: Contenido editado, muchas gracias por la corrección. Lo habia arreglado pensando que el cambio bueno era lo del parseInt y la falta de la base, cuando era lo de la implementación de la función isNaN.